# Is justify text available in SwiftUi yet? how to justify?

Tags: swiftui

I notice the `.justify` modifier is not available to use. How can we `justify text`? is there any other component other than `Text` which has the `justify` feature or any other way?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
                 
        ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
           Text("loonngg textttttt tt DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD").padding(.horizontal, 50.0) 
                
            
        }
            }
        }
 
 
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use representable wrapper on `UILabel`. Below is simplified demo.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
struct Demo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        JustifiedText("loonngg textttttt tt DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD")
          .padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
    }
}

struct JustifiedText: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let value: String
    init(_ string: String) {
        value = string
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.textAlignment = .justified
        view.numberOfLines = 0
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.text = value
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: unless I provide it with a `.frame (height: 100)` etc it just limits it self to a one line of text and truncates the excess. Why it doesn't expand to multi lines it self?

Comment: and I see in my app, the font is in different sizes in each line. how to set a font size for the whole text? I don't understand why `swiftui` hasn't made a `.justified` by default, I see similar questions dates back 2020, so we don't have to go through unnecessary trouble.